# Nested form has_many through issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, has-many-through

I have two models which are related with has_many :through association.
I have user & software_license models associated through user_software_license model. I am trying to save data using nested form, but I am getting errors

my models :

```
user.rb

  has_many :software_licenses, through: :user_software_licenses
  has_many :user_software_licenses 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :software_licenses, :allow_destroy => true

software_license.rb

    has_many :users, through: :user_software_licenses
    has_many :user_software_licenses
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_software_licenses

user_software_license.rb

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :software_license
```

my nested form :

```
= f.fields_for :software_licenses do |software_license|
  = render :partial => "users/software_licenses", :locals => {:f => software_license}
  = link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :user_software_licenses, true, "users/software_licenses"
```

this is how I am initialising it in my controller

```
user.software_licenses.build
```

and when I click on 'add more' button in nested form after submitting form I am getting parameters like this :

```
 "software_licenses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"2"}},
 "user_software_licenses"=>{"id"=>"2"},
```

Comment: can you please add error logs and strong params and controller methods?

Comment: def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit!
end

Comment: def edit
    @contractor = User.find(params[:id])
     user.software_licenses.build  
  end